# Does the HP ProBook 4530S play an 8GB Dual Layer DVD?

Tags: dvd

Will the HP ProBook 4530-series read or play Dual-Layer DVDs?

Comment: Hello @randon... what's wrong here? I am asking about a piece of info.. If any body knows!

Comment: Hi @Daziplqa - I agree with random that this question makes no sense.  My apologies if English isn't your first language, but we have *no idea what this means*.  Can you please edit your question to provide a more detailed explanation?

Comment: I'm *guessing* the he wants to know if the HP Probook 4530-series will read or play Dual-Layer DVDs...I'm going to say yes but the best thing to do would find the spec sheet of the laptop and try and find it there. As this question stands, it is pretty uncomprehensible.

Comment: Well, it's not like it can't be answered.

Comment: The answer is **yes** according to HP. The included DVD drive is a `DVD+/-RW SuperMulti DL`, where the "DL" denotes support for dual-layer DVDs.

Comment: As for this not being a real question, it doesn't take much deductive reasoning to figure out what Daziplqa was asking, especially after the question and title were revised.

Comment: @ Paperjam, post your comment as an answer please. link to the HP document also, thanks.